# zero conditional and first conditional

Tags: conditionals, first-conditional

We use the so-called zero conditional when the result of the condition is always true.

What about following situation.
Let's say that we have a poorly written application. :)
and I complain that it simply does not work.
It is always true for this version of application. 
Zero conditional sounds good to me.
Is it wrong to use first conditional here?

- "if I press a button it crashes."
- "if I press a button it will crash."

thanks!

Comment: Are "zero conditional" and "first conditional" perhaps terms from ESL?

Comment: I have no idea. I was thinking that they are common and well known.

Comment: No, they are known almost exclusively to teachers and learners of English as a second or foreign language.

Comment: It does not really matter, does it? The question is what would be better to use in the case I described above.

Comment: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The zero, or present, conditional, using the present tense in both clauses, means, in the words of ‘An A-Z of  English Grammar’ by Leech and others, that ‘the condition can be true at any time’. In the case of the example, whenever I press a button, assuming I do, it crashes. In practice, it suggests that the speaker has indeed pressed a button on at least one occasion.

In the first conditional, the main clause envisages the likely result if the condition is fulfilled. In the example, I may or may not press a button, but pressing the button will certainly result in a crash. There is no indication in the sentence that the speaker has yet pressed a button.

Comment: I hope it helps.