# "When people do make changes" - which tense is this?

Tags: tenses

Which tense are sentences like:

- "When people do make changes good things happen"
- "Even if monkeys can play an important role, their actions can pose risk to the general public"

Answer (score 1):

Those sentences are both [zero-conditional sentences](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/zero-conditional.html).

The first sentence has an emphatic *do* thrown in.

The second sentence uses the modal verb *can* to express possibility.

Comment: A conditional with a when-clause?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Exactly.  The formulation is the same.  You can substitute *when* for *if* or vice-versa, it just changes the "intensity" (for lack of a better word) of the conditional statement.

Comment: So I guess based on the link you have provided the tense is present simple?

Comment: There seems to be a lack of consensus about terminology.'[The term zero-conditional] is known almost exclusively to teachers and learners of English as a second or foreign language.' –  [Barrie England Sep 12 '13](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126645/zero-conditional-and-first-conditional)